# JQuery / Ajax - form not submitting after using preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have seen several questions and answers regarding this topic. But after hours of testing... None have worked for me.. Can anyone assist in my problem!??

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $( "#search_form" ).on('submit',function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this);
   $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_validate.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {host:host},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.status == 'ok'){ 
          form.submit();
          }
   });
});
```

This is giving me an infinite loop...
My task is:
- default action to prevent the form submission.
- if data.status == ok, then, submit the form.

Comment: From your code what you are doing is submiting a form and on success submits it again. Infinite loop is expected. Why do you submit form after succes?

Comment: I guess i was not clear in my description... Sorry.

Once a user clicks the submit button on the form. It is prevented from POST with the event.preventDefault(). It then performs an ajax query. If the return status is 'ok' from that query then the form is submitted, otherwise, the user remains on the form page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit prevented');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    //submit the underlying form element to bypass the jquery handler
    e.target.submit();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632085/jquery-ajax-form-not-submitting-after-using-preventdefault">
  <button>Submit me</button>
</form>
```

So taking this concept, you should just be able to change your code to the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#search_form" ).on('submit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this; //This line changed from "$(this)" to just "this"

    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_validate.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {host:host},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.status === 'ok'){ 
          form.submit();
          //or optionally you could do
          //event.target.submit();
          //both "this" and "event.target" should point to the form submitted
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Btw, when I copied your logic to show the change, there was a syntax error with your success parameter not being closed properly.  Make sure you are closing things properly and that your console does not tell you about any errors.

Comment: Thank's for the response. I tried your method with the ajax request inside the function. But it returns an error..

Uncaught TypeError: event.target.submit is not a function

P.S - I must use ajax within my code.

Comment: What do you mean "inside the function"?  I only used a setTimeout in the answer to show a delay between the submit and the following submit.  The take away from this answer, and really the only thing you would change in your code, would be to change `var form = $(this);` to `var form = this;` which would cause the following `form.submit()` to be done on the element, and not a jQuery object. @Leo505

Comment: Otherwise your logic would be `event.target.submit()` since you named the argument to the callback `event`, rather than `e` like my logic did.

Comment: Using the event or the form.submit method both return errors.

with form.submit() method
(Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function) - var form = this coded too.

with the event.target.submit() method
(Uncaught TypeError: event.target.submit is not a function) - i have the event coded in the function arguement

Comment: Then I'd need to see what you are doing/trying, because as you can see by running the solution on this site, it works.

Comment: Hi.

I guess i was not clear in my description... Sorry. Once a user clicks the submit button on the form. It is prevented from POST with the event.preventDefault(). It then performs an ajax query. If the return status is 'ok' from that query then the form is submitted, otherwise, the user remains on the form page. Not sure how i can show you my code on jsfiddle or equivalent as the ajax query goes to a php file.

Comment: @Leo505 I update my answer to show how you would modify your logic.  I also made note of a syntax error you had in your original snippet from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Toplars answer and i still got the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: event.target.submit is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function
```

The only way i got this working was throwing the ajax query in a function and then acting upon the result of the function to allow or deny the POST. I had to also add 'async:false' to force ajax to wait for the response of the query to allow the  code =  variable to fulfil. See below for the code:

```
  var x = ajax();
  if(x == 0){
  event.preventDefault();
  }

function ajax(){
    code = null;

   $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_validate.php",
        type: 'POST',
        async:false,
        data: {host:host},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.status == 'ok'){ 
          code = 1;
          }else if(data.status == 'error'){ 
          code = 0;
          }
  });
return code;
}
```